# Returning CSV or JSON from Spring Controllers using Message Converters

Tags: json, spring, csv, converters

I am trying to configure my Spring application to return either JSON or CSV based on user requested media Type. In order to do that I have set up my  tag like below

```
<context:annotation-config />


<bean id ="contentNegotiationManager" class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="favorPathExtension" value="false"/>
    <property name="favorParameter"  value="true"/>
    <property name="parameterName" value="mediaType"/>
    <property name="defaultContentType"  value="test/csv"/>

    <property name="mediaTypes">
        <map>
            <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
            <entry key="csv" value="test/csv"/>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>

<mvc:annotation-driven content-negotiation-manager="contentNegotiationManager">
    <mvc:message-converters register-defaults="true">
        <bean class="com.data.api.util.CSVMessageConverter"/>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
            <property name="objectMapper">
                <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperFactoryBean">
                    <property name="modules" ref="jodaModule"/>
                    <property name="featuresToDisable">
                        <array>
                            <util:constant static-field="com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS"/>
                        </array>
                    </property>
                    <property name="defaultViewInclusion" value="false"/>
                    <property name="failOnUnknownProperties" value="false"/>
                </bean>

            </property>
            <property name="supportedMediaTypes">
                <array>
                    <util:constant static-field="org.springframework.http.MediaType.ALL" />
                </array>

            </property>
        </bean>
<bean id="jodaModule" class="com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.JodaModule"/>
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

Below is my CSVMessageConverter class

public class CSVMessageConverter extends AbstractHttpMessageConverter {

```
public static final MediaType MEDIA_TYPE = new MediaType("text", "csv", Charset.forName("utf-8"));

public CSVMessageConverter() {
    super(MEDIA_TYPE);
}

@Override
protected boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
    return true;
}

@Override
protected CSVMessage readInternal(Class<? extends CSVMessage> clazz, HttpInputMessage inputMessage) throws IOException, HttpMessageNotReadableException {
    CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(inputMessage.getBody()));
    return new CSVMessage(reader.readAll());
}

@Override
protected void writeInternal(CSVMessage message, HttpOutputMessage outputMessage) throws IOException, HttpMessageNotWritableException {
    CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputMessage.getBody()));
    if (! Strings.isNullOrEmpty(message.getHeader())) {
        writer.writeNext(new String[] { "#" + message.getHeader() } );
    }
    for (String[] row: message.getRows()) {
        writer.writeNext(row);
    }
    writer.close();
}
```

}

and My Controller does this

```
public class TestController { 
public @ResponseBody List<Records> getHits(@PathVariable("domain") name  domainName,
                                       @PathVariable("property") Name propertyName,
                                       @RequestParam(value = "start", required = true)  @DateTimeFormat(pattern = datePattern) Date startDate,
                                       @RequestParam(value = "end", required = true) @DateTimeFormat(pattern = datePattern) Date endDate,
                                       HttpServletRequest request) {
//This returns an arralist of records
}    
}
```

I am unable to get my CSVMessageConverter to work. It is throwing cannot cast ArrayList to CSVMessage. What am I doing wrong ? It works fine with JSON but If i request for "text/csv" it blows up.

Can someone explain how Spring uses MessageConverters and WhatI can do to make the above code work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by fixing my CSVMessageConverter class. It was expecting CSVMessage class in readInternal/WriteExternal. I changed this to ArrayList.class and these methods get called fine.